# H2 Database Update multiple columns

Tags: database, h2

Good Day,

I am trying to figure out how to update multiple columns in h2 database. Single column is easy like this:

UPDATE TABLENAME SET COLUMN1='X' WHERE ID='2'

But I want to update COLUMN2 and COLUMN3 also. How do i do this?!!

Answer (score 4):

The regular [syntax to update](http://h2database.com/html/grammar.html#update) multiple columns is:

```
UPDATE TABLENAME 
SET COLUMN1='X', COLUMN2='Y', COLUMN3='Z' 
WHERE ID='2'
```

Some database also support:

```
UPDATE TABLENAME 
SET (COLUMN1, COLUMN2, COLUMN3) = 
('X', 'Y', 'Z') WHERE ID='2'
```